# Discord.js - Updating a MessageEmbed in the following code

Tags: node.js, discord.js, embed, updates, message

So, I have (this is only part of it) the following code, but I can't figure out this whole updating a sent embed thing...

The coding is all working if I send a new embed every time, but I don't want to clutter the channel; thus attempting to update the first embed.

Code:

```
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
let hangembedStart = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("Let's get started!")
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setThumbnail(sicon)
    .addField('Word:', asterisc)
message.channel.send(hangembedStart);
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
    maxMatches: 9,
    time: 30000
});
collector.on('collect', m => {
    if (m.content === 'cancel') {
        inProgress = false;
        delete guessed;
        collector.stop();
        return;
    }
    if (lowChar === text) {
        message.channel.send(`Congratulations, you guessed the word!`);
        inProgress = false;
        delete guessed;
        collector.stop();
        return;
    }
    let hits = checkChar(lowChar, text);
    if (hits === 0) {
        let hangembedGuess = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription("Hangman - The Game - In progress")
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setThumbnail(sicon)
            .addField('Word:', reveal)
            .addField('Guessed:', guessed.join(" "))
        message.channel.send(hangembedGuess);
    } else if (hits > 0) {
        let hangembedGuess = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription("Hangman - The Game - In progress")
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setThumbnail(sicon)
            .addField('Word:', reveal)
            .addField('Guessed:', guessed.join(" "))
        message.channel.send(hangembedGuess);
    }
});
collector.on('end', collected => {
    message.channel.send(`Game ended, word was: ${text}!`);
    inProgress = false;
    delete guessed;
    //collector.stop();
});
```

How the ... can I update the first embed in this code, instead of sending a new one each time?
I tried using message.edit() but that triggers:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user

I've googled, read, searched, tried, tested just about everything I've come across, but can't wrap my head around this one...

Comment: How are you triggering the message send? the reason it might not work is because you are attempting the edit the message the person sent instead of editing the embed that the bot sent.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that's the issue as well.
Here's the code;
```

Comment: wheres the code

Comment: Code was too long for a comment, but I posted it on Pastebin.
https://pastebin.com/YpJk0sJD

Comment: you could just get the last message that the bot sent in the channel and edit that

Comment: That's what I was hoping, but feeling a bit lost on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted!!

Added the following line:

```
const hangmanMessage = await message.channel.send(hangembedStart);
//above
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
```

Then changed the following line(s):

```
message.channel.send(hangembedGuess);
//to this
hangmanMessage.edit(hangembedGuess);
```

Now it updates the first embed, instead of sending a new one each time :D